# Prism.Forms DI: How to avoid multiple singleton instances?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Let's assume we have an interface IPushNotificationService which is implemented by PushNotificationService and should live as a singleton service inside my Prism.Forms app.

What is the correct way of registering this service in RegisterTypes method so that we will always have one single instance at the time?

**Approach 1:**
Override RegisterTypes and call RegisterSingleton.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPushNotificationService, PushNotificationService>();
}
```

**Approach 2:**
Override RegisterTypes and check if the service is already registered. If yes it is not already present in the DI container, call RegisterSingleton.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    if (!containerRegistry.IsRegistered<IPushNotificationService>())
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPushNotificationService, PushNotificationService>();
    }
}
```

**Other Approach?** - The ultimate goal is to have a single instance of a singleton-registered service at a particular time. If I navigate back using the Back Button in Xamarin Android and then relaunch the app, I get multiple instance of a singleton-registered service. How can I avoid this?

Comment: When doing this (back button plus restart) while debugging, does the debugger stop after back button? Do you hit a break point at `RegisterTypes` once or twice in the process?

Comment: The debugger does not stop when the Back button is pressed. However, the Android app starts with SplashActivity --> MainActivity (both LaunchMode.SingleTop) which means, we have a complete restart of the app.

Comment: How do you diagnose the multiple instances? Is a breakpoint at the constructor of `PushNotificationService` hit twice?

Comment: In RegisterTypes I call
var registeredInstances = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPushNotificationService>>();
which return all registered instances of IPushNotificationService. Now, since the DI container is never disposed, it returns +1 instance with every time the Xamarin app is restarted.

Comment: The Prism team don't monitor stackoverflow, raise an issue on GitHub and i'm sure they'll get back to you :) [prism issues](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues)

Comment: At least you guys are trying to help :) Meanwhile I found some new hope on getting this problem solved. One part was to set LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask on MainActivity (I used to have LaunchMode.SingleTop before). Sill investigating on this; going to update this thread as soon as I get some news.

Comment: Which container do you use and which version, btw? The behaviour of the `IContainerRegistry` is essentially undefined and just mirrors the behaviour of the wrapped container, so Unity or DryIOC or Autofac may make a difference here

Comment: That's a good point. All these containers have slightly different behaviour in handling registration, resolves and disposal of singleton services. In most apps I'm using Prism with DryIoC. In another recent project we're not using Prism but SimpleInjector as DI container. The problem is always the same. I might create a small sample app. Seems like the SplashActivity has also some influence.